# How to create session in php with a tag on another page?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am working on php project where i have 2 tables `users` and
`company`. user will first registerd himself and then create company
for himself. one user can have multiple companies to access. so that i
have one page that will show authorised companies to particular user.
Now, i have to visit particular company of particular user. let's say
user A have 3 companies COM-1, COM-2, COM-3. I create session for
user.so i can get below query and results:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from company where `userId`= '".$_SESSION['userid']."' ");          
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
{
    if ($row>0) 
    {
        ?>
        <div><a href='dash.php?=<?php echo $row["companyId"];?>' name="" value='<?php echo $row["companyId"];?>'><?php echo $row['companyName'];?></a></div>    
       <?php    
    }
}
?>
```

Now i have to visit selected company only. for that i have to create
session of company how can get it.

Comment: no need  session just pass the company id as get parameter like this href='dash.php?company_id=<?php echo $row["companyId"];?>'

Comment: side-info: `<a>` doesn't have a property `value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no need of session, you just need to pass company_id variable via GET. Then you will get company_id easily on dash.php.

simple change this line

```
<a href='dash.php?company_id='<?php echo $row["companyId"];?>' ><?php echo $row['companyName'];?></a>
```

dash.php

```
$_GET["company_id"]; // this is your company id
```